# Unable to modify component props from React DevTools for Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

I am developing a React application and have setup webpack to package my code into bundles.

However when I load my application in Chrome with React DevTools and try to modify the props of a component via the extension, it is not changing the value or re-rendering with the new value.

Below is my `webpack.config.js`

```js
'use strict';

const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    agile: './client/js/agile.jsx.js',
    vendor: [
      'domready',
      'react',
      'react-dom',
      'classnames'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: 'public/js',
    publicPath: '/js/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel' }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({names: ['vendor'], minChunks: Infinity}),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  target: 'web',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  stats: {
    color: true,
    modules: false,
    reasons: false
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    contentBase: './public/'
  }
};
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

I also tried to remove the `HotModuleReplacementPlugin` used above and ran my app without the `webpack-dev-server`. Neither of them worked.

Versions:

- React - 15.0.1
- React DevTools - 0.14.9
- Node - v4.4.1
- Chrome - 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit) on Mac OSX

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know if this qualifies as an answer, but I don't yet have over 50 points so I can't add a comment.

It looks like this is an issue caused by a [React optimization](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/314) that was first reported in January. At the end of that thread there is an open [PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/pull/356) that is supposed to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the GitHub item and PR. I think there is a fix in but not yet released.